# jquery select second and third cell of current tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m new with jquery.Below is my html table which is in content page.In master page i have also other tables. 
    when i select table cell from 'tableAppointment' by dragging. it selects all table cell within a page. user has restriction to select only second and third cell of current tr.if user selects more than three rows then give alert("time slot not more than 45 minutes.")..How can i do that with jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Drag selection example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function ()
        {
            var active = false;

            $('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2), #tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(3)').mousedown(function (ev)
            {
                active = true;
                $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight"); // clear previous selection
                ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
                $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
            });

            $('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2), #tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(3)').mousemove(function (ev)
            {
                if (active)
                {
                    $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                    $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
                }
                if ($('.temp_selected').length > 6)
                {
                    alert("Time slot not more than 45 minutes.")
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $(document).mouseup(function (ev)
            {
                active = false;
                $('.temp_selected').removeClass('.temp_selected');

            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .csstdhighlight
        {
            background-color: #ccffcc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tableAppointment" cellspacing="1" width="50%" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                <b>Patient Name</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="70px">
                8:00AM
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                0
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                15
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                30
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                45
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                9:00AM
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                0
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                15
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                30
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                45
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `$('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2)')`

for `alert("time slot not more than 45 minutes.")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function ()
        {
            var active = false;


            $("#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2), #tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(3)").mousedown(function (ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
                if(get_num_rows() > 3)
                { 
                    alert("time slot not more than 45 minutes");
                    return false; 
                }
                active = true;
                num_rows_selected = num_rows_selected + 1;
                $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight"); 
                $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
            });

            $("td").mousemove(function (ev)
            {
                if (active)
                {
                    $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                }
            });

            function get_num_rows() {
                var count = 0;
                $("#tableAppointment tr").each(function(){
                    if($(this).find('td.csstdhighlight').length > 0)
                    {
                      count++;
                    }
                });
                return count;
            }

            $(document).mouseup(function (ev)
            {
                active = false;
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: i have applies but it not works it select all cells within a page when dragging

Comment: have you replaced `$("#tableAppointment td")` with `$('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2)')` ?

Comment: i have change on mouse move event it select only second cell i have to select second and third cell of current tr. and what about alert("time slot not more than 45 minutes.")

Comment: `$('#tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(2), #tableAppointment tr td:nth-child(3)')` this will select 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: No rishabh i have chk but it works again like past select all cells within page

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
$("td").mousemove(function (ev) {
    if (active){
        $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
    }
    if($('.csstdhighlight').length > 2){
        alert("time slot not more than 45 minutes.")
    }
});
```

So if there are more than 2 elements containing the **csstdhighlight** class. Then it will alert the error.

---

***Second attempt:***

```
$("#tableAppointment td").mousedown(function (ev)
        {
            active = true;
            $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight"); // clear previous selection
            ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
            $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
            $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
        });

        $("td").mousemove(function (ev)
        {
            if (active)
            {
                $(this).addClass("csstdhighlight");
                $(this).addClass("temp_selected");
            }
            if($('.temp_selected').length > 2){
                alert("time slot not more than 45 minutes.")
            }
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function (ev)
        {
            active = false;
            $('.temp_selected').removeClass('temp_selected');
        });
```

Comment: iiya: i have chk but it pop ups every time when i click anywhere on page

Comment: This should only appear when there are more than two elements with that class. Before you select any element, is that class already applied to certain elements?

Comment: csstdhighlight class is already applied to selected cels of current tr

Comment: i think alert is not on mouse move

Comment: If you make me a jsfiddle example i will have a better idea of how your script works :)

Comment: i m not able to type html in jsfiddle

Comment: if u can check on ur machine then it better

Comment: chk now i have edit my code u have to just copy the code paste in ur html file and run  :)

Comment: My bad. Replace $('.temp_selected').removeClass('.temp_selected'); with $('.temp_selected').removeClass('temp_selected');

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cyjye/

Note: the only problem you could have is that the alert window pops up and disrupts the mouseup event and thus the class is not removed. Solution: don't use an alert popup.

Comment: if user selcts mor than three row then i wnt alert

Comment: Mate, you changed that one yourself. Simply change the 6 to 3:

    if ($('.temp_selected').length > 6)

Comment: how to remove css for cell(added after alert) after alert

Comment: and also start selection from second row second cell..if u see code then it also select "Patient name" cell